# Download MODIS data for Mexico

Tags: data, remote-sensing, imagery, modis, mexico

I would like to download MODIS npp images for Mexico but I cannot figure out which files correspond to the country. How can I associate each tile to its location without looking at the million of browsing images. I am an experienced python and R user if that helps.

I am manually downloading the images from this link: http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD17A3.055/2000.01.01/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can find the H and V index in all MODIS product file name. These indices refer to the grid below (from the [MODIS Website](http://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODLAND_grid.html)). For instance you have H8V6 (MOD17A3.A2000001.h08v06.055.2011276103801.hdf).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may check the "pyMODIS" software, a Free and Open Source Python library to work with MODIS data. It can bulk-download, mosaik and reproject:

http://www.pymodis.org

Answer (score 2):

MODIS imagery is publicly available via satellite imagery service called [**LandViewer**](https://eos.com/landviewer). You can download it with ease via the toolbar on the right or use dozens of tools for image analysis directly on the platform.

Besides that there are already ready-made tools for obtaining multispectral indices, flexible processing of data on AOI, elementary clustering, using a raster calculator, visualization of scenes in 3D using digital elevation models, changes in territories based on multi-temporal multispectral analysis, as well as creating ready-made animations of changes in terrain.

An example of MODIS imagery taken over Mexico can be seen [**HERE**](https://eos.com/landviewer/?lat=25.63905&lng=-105.62805&z=8&preset=passiveLowSensors&id=LV-TUNE-NDNB-NC5B-MjAx-OTA5-MC5o-MDh2-MDYu-MDA2-LjIw-MTkw-OTkx-ODE0-NDc%3D&b=Red,Green,Blue&anti).

Comment: **Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software/test".